# What does symmetry imply about the solution in mathematics? (Example: Gauss' law)

Tags: physics, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics

Suppose you have an infinite cylinder and are considering a field $\mathbf{D}$ caused by physical elements within the cylinder such that it satisfies  $\int \mathbf{D}\cdot d\mathbf{a} = Q_{free}$. Where $Q_{free}$ refers to the so-called "free charges".

In mathematical terms, why does it follow that this field *has* to be radial (without resorting to physical arguments)?

I can see that because the cylinder is infinite the only thing which is needed to specify the field is the distance $s$ from the central axis. But I don't see why the solution can't have some non-radial components as well...

**Is there any mathematical argument about symmetries that guarantees a specific form of a solution?**

As an example of exploiting symmetries and knowing a priori the form of the solution is Laplace's equation $\nabla^2 V(x,y,z)=0$. If one sees that regardless of translations in $z$ the environment is always the same, then one can easily conclude the potential $V$ has no dependence on $z$.

Comment: If the charges are not free, if there is a $z$-dependence to the charge distribution, then there is indeed a $z$-dependence to the potential (and hence the field), but, still no angular feature for a line charge as there can be no distinction in terms of angle from one "side" of the wire to another. If we had a finite wire in radius with different charge distribution for different angle then the potential would inherit an angular dependence. The charges being "free" and the wire being a "conductor" forces the translational symmetry you mention.

Comment: for specific mathematics of symmetries and conservation laws, we can study Noether's Theorem.

Comment: What you say is valid for conservative fields but $\mathbf{D}$ need not be conservative. Namely, I cannot consider a potential for such a field. Also, I doubt this could have relevance with Noether's Theorems since it isn't about any conserved quantity.

Comment: Ok, so what exactly do you mean by $\mathbf D$?

Comment: The electric displacement. It can be the case that it is non-conservative. But I didn't want to get into physics and was wondering if mathematics had anything to say about such a thing. Namely about the statement: "it has to be radial since it is an infinite cylinder" (which many people prove, in the case of the electric field, by considering individual charges).

Comment: You also wish to assume a linear dielectric media?

Comment: Nope. I wouldn't like to assume that.